# How Can I Do Android Numpad Programmatically

Tags: android, keyboard, numpad

[image: Numpad]

I have this layout. But how can I write any EditText "1" when I click "1 button".

But I have more than one edittext. I want to write "1" when I click "1 button" to any focused edittext.

How can I do it?

Comment: [EditText#setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) method is all you need

Comment: edit.settext("1") on the click of button.

Comment: I see u but in the edittext which I want to write there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OnfocusChanged() of the textViews to know which one is selected. It would look like :

```
private EditText mCurrentEditText;

private mFocusListener = new OnFocusChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            mCurrentEditText = (EditText) v;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your clickListener :

```
void onClick() {
    if(mCurrentEdittext != null) {
        mCurrentEditText.setText("1");
    }
}
```

Finally you set the correct listener to your EditText and buttons.